# Django: Passing a parameter into a URL pattern name

Tags: django

In the example below, I'm trying to use the URL pattern name (ie, 'update_profile') instead of the absolute path (/profile/str:pk/update) in one of my views. This way if I later change my url path, I don't have to go an change each time I used the absolute path.

My question: how do I pass 'pk' into a pattern name?
I've tried things like:

`success_url = 'update_profile' % (pk)`

But that doesn't seem to work.

**urls.py**

```
path('/profile/<str:pk>/update', views.ProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_profile'),
```

**views.py**

```
def submit_profile_form(request, pk):
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        success_url = 'update_profile' //  <------ How do I pass 'pk' in here?
        ...
        return redirect(success_url)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`redirect(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) accepts positional and named parameters, so you can write:

```
def submit_profile_form(request, pk):
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        success_url = 'update_profile'
        # …
        return redirect(success_url, pk=pk)
```

If the primary key is a number, you might want to use the `pk` path converter instead:

```
path(
    '/profile/<int:pk>/update',
    views.ProfileUpdateView.as_view(),
    name='update_profile'
),
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I knew the answer was simple. Thanks a bunch mate!